# Change value in Spark Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataset and what I need to do is looping through all values in all rows of this Dataset and change the value when some conditions are meet.

For example, I want to change all the value bigger than 5 into 0. So I loop through the Dataset and change the value into 0.

My problem is that I don't find a way to change the value in Dataset. Are there anyway to do so in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` or `select` function in dataframe or dataset in spark

This is how you can do it in scala, I hope you can convert it in Java

```
//dummy dataframe with two column id and value
val df = Seq(
  ("a", 1),
  ("b", 4),
  ("c", 2),
  ("d", 6),
  ("e", 10),
  ("f", 11)
).toDF("id", "value")

//Now this will change the all value with greater than 5 to 0
val newDF = df.withColumn("value", when($"value" > 5, 0).otherwise($"value"))
```

Same with `select`

```
val newDF = df.select($"id", when($"value" > 5, 0).otherwise($"value").as("value"))
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|id |value|
+---+-----+
|a  |1    |
|b  |4    |
|c  |2    |
|d  |0    |
|e  |0    |
|f  |0    |
+---+-----+
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

On the lines of what [Shankar Koirala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685593/3759060) suggested, below is the java solution for the same:

```
dataSet = dataSet.withColumn("value",when(col("value").gt(5),0).otherwise(col("value")));
```

Comment: Can we do df.withColumn("*",..) if we intend to run the replacement in all the columns?